# Instantiating objects on both sides of assignment operator in Scala; how does it work

Tags: scala, syntax

I want to understand the mechanism behind the following line:

```
 val List(x) = Seq(1 to 10)
```

What is the name of this mechanism? Is this the same as typecasting, or is there something else going on? (Tested in Scala 2.11.12.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is actually the expression

```
Seq(1 to 10)
```

This does not create a sequence of 10 elements, but a sequence containing a single `Range` object. So when you do this

```
val List(x) = Seq(1 to 10)
```

`x` is assigned to that `Range` object.

If you want a `List` of numbers, do this:

```
(1 to 10).toList
```

---

The pattern `List(x)` will only match if the expression on the right is an instance of `List` containing a single element. It will not match an empty `List` or a `List` with more than one element.

In this case it happens to work because the constructor for `Seq` actually returns an instance of `List`.

Comment: This makes sense to me, but I still don't quite grok it. For example, why does `val List(x) = Seq(1 to 10)` run but `val List(x) = Seq(1, 2)` throws a `MatchError`?

Comment: Because `List(x)` is a constructor pattern matching for a `List` which, hold one element on which `x` is match against. `Seq(1, 2)` is a `Seq` which holds two elements and thus can't be successfully matched with the foresaid pattern.

Comment: In case you need more example, if you try `val List(x, y) = Seq(1, 2)` and `val List(x) = Seq(1)`, it'll work because you have the right number of elements.

Comment: The right word would be ["pattern"](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html), not an "expression". I think it's better to distinguish those two things in this context.

Answer (score 7):

The mechanism is called *Pattern Matching*.

Here is the official documentation: https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/pattern-matching.html

This works also in for comprehensions:

```
for{
 People(name, firstName) <- peoples
} yield s"$firstName $name"
```

To your example:

```
val List(x) = Seq(1 to 10)
```

`x` is the content of that List - in your case `Range 1 to 10` (You have a list with one element).

If you have really a list with more than one element, that would throw an exception

```
val List(x) = (1 to 10).toList // -> ERROR: undefined
```

So the correct pattern matching would be:

```
val x::xs = (1 to 10).toList
```

Now `x` is the first element (head) and `xs` the rest (tail).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The mechanism makes sense to me in a pattern matching context, but I'm not still not 100% sure how I should read the code line in my post. I also don't understand why, after running the above line, the type of x is `scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive`, and not `List[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive]`.

Answer (score 5):

This technique is called object destructuring. Haskell provides a similar feature. Scala uses pattern matching to achieve this.

The method used in this case is Seq#unapplySeq:
https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Seq.html

Answer (score 3):

You can think of

```
val <pattern> = <value>
<next lines>
```

as

```
<value> match {
  case <pattern> => 
    <next lines>
}
```

This doesn't happen only when `<pattern>` is just a variable or a variable with a type.